# using python in a pipe

Tags: python, console, pipe

I am reading a text file with cat and piping it through grep, etc
Now I have several lines containing numbers

There is a final operation that I don't think there is a operator to do what I want so I would like to do it with a python script.

Is there a way that I can incorporate this python script in the pipe?

For example

If I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

num = input()

print(num)
```

and I make this script executable, I can run it by calling it
but I cannot put it into a pipe

It says `processa.py: command not found`

Is there a way that `processa.py` can be considered a command and take input and output from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script `processa.py` is located in a path which is defined in your $PATH

Check your $PATH with:

`echo $PATH`

Some possible locations for your script can be:

- /usr/local/bin
- /home/YOURUSERNAME/bin
- or any other path you want, but you has to be define it in your $PATH

To define it to $PATH use following command
`export PATH=$PATH:path/to/your/dir`